# preg match not allowing apostrophes/single quote (')

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I cannot get pregmatch to accept single(') or double (") quotes. I am attempting this in php the pattern is located in a "textarea."

I would like to allow both quote types but neither are being accepted. Therefore halting input into the database.

The pattern I have is

`pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.,()'!?:"\s]"`

The preg match I have is

```
!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()'!?:"\s]*$/", $description)
```

I have searched and tried everything.

When I try this

```
"/^['\a-zA-Z0-9.,()!?:\s]*$/"
```

it returns Lisa\'s instead of Lisa's

Comment: Escape the quotes

Comment: This is the **wrong** way to prevent SQL injection. Use **[prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)** with **[bound parameters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)**. See **[this page](https://phptherightway.com/#databases)** and **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)** for some good examples.

Comment: @anubhava That is **bad** advice. To truly be safe from SQL injections you  need to use prepared statements.

Comment: I am also using prepared statements.

Comment: @kh67 If you are single quotes will not break your queries and halt execution of your code.

Comment: So you escape the quote in the regex and it now works or there are additional issues?

Comment: Your regex `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()'!?:\"\s]*$/"` should match strings with single and double quotation marks. Are you sure those are not curly quotes?

Comment: "Therefore halting input into the database." How else would a single quote do this?

Comment: My interpretation of the question would be that these are characters the OP allows in the DB. Any other character should stop input.

Comment: They say they want to accept them so that can't be true

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was pretty sure. so I tested it. in web form appears straight and in wordperfect it is indeed curly. Confusing. Any suggestion how to allow either? Assuming users not know the difference either.

Comment: @JohnConde Are you saying that with binding parameters that preg match is not needed? I thought both were needed for optimal security.

Comment: To allow any "regular" curly quotes you may try to add them, `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()'!?:\"\s’‘“”]*$/"`

Comment: @kh67 Yes, that is what I am saying. If you use prepared statements you don't have to worry about quotes. Removing them is incorrect and a common myth.

Comment: @JohnConde beside the quotes is there anything else to worry about by not having a pattern or preg match? What I am asking is if I remove the pattern and preg match and leave binding parameters (of course) is there anything I need to avoid?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know this is probably stupid... but how do I do that? It only shows one selection on keyboard.

Comment: @kh67 That all depends on what a valid value is for you. IF you don't want HTML in your values you need to remove that, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Filter the input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), then run your check to make sure you're not storing a [malicious bit of HTML or Javascript, or a tag breaker](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). Then once you get to [binding your parameters with PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) for insertion indicate it as a [PARAM_STR](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

```
$description = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'description',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(preg_match("~^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()\"'!?:\s]*$~", $description)){
       //Call functions to prepare statements and insert into db here.
       //...
       $stmt->bindValue(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your preg match now allows single quote lets leave it and get the slashes removed before inserting into the database.

Try this:

```
!preg_match("/^['\a-zA-Z0-9.,()!?:\s]*$/", $description))
```

And then before you bind your parameters in your prepared statement add this line of code:

```
  $description = stripslashes(htmlentities($description));
```

@John Conde was correct. Make sure you always use prepared statements and bind your parameters.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: When I used this it now allows all the other characters I do not want. Mainly I do not want spam website links in the database like `http://` for instance. the link is removed but the web address still shows